# Displaying html in a table view cell

Tags: iphone, html, uitableview

I am working a rss reader app for iphone  . What are my options for displaying entry summary in rss feed ( which could be html) in a tableviewcell without compromising scroll performance . 
I dont control the feed so html in summary section is out of my control .

I am thinking of uiwebview would be my last option ( so rss feeds have images and stuff in there, unfortunately ) . I was thinking if there was a way to extract summary text from html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently saw a presentation on Three20 (http://groups.google.com/group/three20/) that included a few things that might help you.

This is the specific thing I'm referring to: http://mattvague.com/three20-custom-cells-iphone-tutorial

Comment: Thanks . I just plugged it in my app ..it seems to choke if it encounters html that it doesnt support.

Comment: ok I was missing setNeedsLayout ..looks fine for now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `WebKit` view, `UIWebView` to present the feed and add it a subview to the `UITableViewCell`.

You need to worry about the cell height and making the `UIWebView` non-scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested I just made a new up-to-date version of my custom cells tutorial, check it out at http://mattvague.com/three20-tttableitem-tutorial

Cheers!