# fetch html tag from database in iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, database, ipad, uitableview

I am new to iPhone developer,

I have inserted this line in my DB,

```
<b>As individuals it is inherent to differ.</b> <i>Each individual's insurance needs and requirements are different from that of the others.</i> <br>LIC's Insurance Plans are policies that talk to you individually and give you the most suitable options that can fit your requirement.
```

after this i am fetching this line from DB, and passing it to `UITableView` then my Table shows
[image]
the only problem is that I don't know how to tell him that its HTML code. when it see `<br>`
then next line will be on the new line or when it see `<b>words of line</b>` the text **words of line** should be in bold while fetching.

*Is It Possible or not ?*

**Any Help will be Appriciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [three20](http://three20.info)?  You can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249569/displaying-html-in-a-table-view-cell%20this) SO post for more information.

Comment: see i have edited my question, and your link is expired in **three20**